# FirebaseError: Document references must have an even number of segments, but users1/YhDZ0LWYGzeuokUCKBrw/RPKOrCzmH9RN6KcNPGSe has 3.]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

```
try {
  const db=getFirestore();
  const variable1=doc(collection(db,'users1'));
  //console.log('doc',doc);
  console.log(variable1);
  const data={
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815

  }
  //const docRef = db.collection("Users").doc("LA").set(data);
  const docRef=await addDoc(variable1,data);
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

The error shown up is :Error adding document:  [FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users1/YhDZ0LWYGzeuokUCKBrw/RPKOrCzmH9RN6KcNPGSe has 3.]

I am trying to add data into firebase Firestore through actual documentation. But, it is not working. Any help to write and read data with the latest version of firebase is also appreciated.